# Having an issue with AWS https deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elb

I am trying to make my elb backend route protected by https. I have a lot of images below showing where I'm at. As far as AWS instruction, I have everthing from the CNAME done to security groups. However, when I call the route I get 'Error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'. I'm working with an apache proxy server. What am I missing thanks!

Below image is the listeners on ELB.
[image]
Here are the listeners from EC2.
[image]
Here is my certificate.
[image]

Here is my security group.
[image]

Here are my inbound rules
[image]

Comment: The security groups are for what? Load balancer or instance

Comment: Your apache proxy server needs to reference the load balancer using your domain name, instead of the DNS name of the load balancer. You can setup a Route53 private hosted zone to make that work. Or you could possibly configure apache to skip SSL certificate validation.

Comment: @MarkB how do i go about that?

Comment: @marsh I don't know because you didn't provide any information about how your apache server is currently setup in your question.

Comment: @MarkB sorry I mean with Route53. Also apache is just default. I didn't make a config fil or anything

Comment: You have to change your Apache config to proxy requests to a domain name that matches the SSL certificate. I can't tell you how to fix any of this in any concrete detail until you tell us how you have configured Apache to proxy requests to the load balancer. Apache doesn't magically proxy requests to backend load balancers out of the box, so the configuration can't be "just default".